# Python: DataFrame restructure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### I have one DataFrame generated from below code

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime

start=datetime(2018, 3, 1)
end=datetime(2018,3,12)
symbol = ['AAPL' , 'IBM' , 'MSFT' , 'GOOG']

Morningstar=web.DataReader(symbol, data_source='morningstar',start=start, end=end)
dfResetMorningstar=Morningstar.reset_index()
pricemine=dfResetMorningstar[['Symbol','Date','Close']]
pricemine.set_index(['Symbol','Date'], inplace=True)
```

Result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7D8WS.png)

---

I would like to transform the dataframe into format similar as below (the data would be the ['Close'] data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZH8w.png)

I'm not sure how this can be achieved using "groupby" comment. Any feedback would be much appreciated. Also open to other ways not using "groupby".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) by first level:

```
pricemine = pricemine['Close'].unstack(0)
```